# Xcode issue with provision.

Tags: ios, xcode

> security: unable to open
>   "/Users/jakereid/Library/MobileDevice/ProvisioningProfiles/.mobileprovision" 
>   for reading: No such file or directory

I am getting this issue, I have absolutely no idea why. I am using source code a friend sent to me and wanted me to test out. It is working perfectly for him. I adjusted the team, the identifier and all the rest. When I run it I get this error. I go to the profiles file and as expected there is no ".mobileprovision", there are my provisions but not a no named one. Could someone please point out how to fix this in Xcode please. Thank you :)

Comment: what is in Code Signing section of Build Settings? did you check it?

Comment: @heximal it is automatic, changing and going to check :) thank you. Changed it to the provision and still the same error.

Comment: I think you need to have provision certificate and Apple Developer Account. You need to sign in to their Apple account. After that, try running.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan i have the certificate and account :)

Comment: Check whether that provision certificate is showing in build setttings for both project & Target. If so then, run it with the certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Have you your own developer account?
If yes, I suggest to let Xcode fix issues, in the Target Settings, select your developer account under: General > Identity > Team

Also, check if your Identity, Certificate and your Provisioning profiles are all valid, [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

You can manually delete your old provisioning profiles and download them again, under Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, select your Identity, View Details, Right-click on the provisioning profile and Move to Trash, Then you can press the Download button.

If you let Xcode fix issues, you should have the following parameters under Build Setting > Code Signing:

- Code Signing Identity: iOS Developer (for all)
- Provisioning Profile: Automatic (for all)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you set up an explicit provisioning profile in Xcode's build settings and then removed this only halfway.

Check your target's "Provisioning Profile" build setting. If it's displayed in bold, it's set (maybe to an empty string). You can remove a setting by selecting it and press the delete key.